# Où trouver des sources fiables sur les gentilés ?

Tags: ressources, noms-propres

Il n’est pas rare de se demander comment on appelle les habitants d’une ville, d’une région, d’un pays, …

Or, contrairement à d’autres langues, le français connaît peu de règles en la matière. On peut difficilement deviner comment s’appelle un habitant de Brive-la-Gaillarde, du Périgord ou du Hainaut : il faut le savoir.

Savez-vous où l’on peut trouver des listes fiables et facilement exploitables de gentilés ?

Comment: Il m'a fallu chercher la définition de « gentilés » dans un dictionnaire. C'est un mot très rare et probablement inconnu de beaucoup de francophones. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gentil%C3%A9s%2Chabitants+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgentil%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabitants%20de%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Si tu as un synonyme plus répandu, je suis preneur, mais je n’en vois pas.

Comment: Je n'en connais pas. L'usage habituel est d'employer comme tu l'as déjà fait la périphrase « les habitants de ... » mais je n'ai rien contre « gentilés » sauf peut-être sa proximité avec « gentillet » ...

Comment: @jlliagre je crois qu'un synonyme est ethnonyme mais je ne sais pas si c'est assez connu.

Comment: @dimitris Proche, mais pas synonyme : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnonymie

Answer (score 4):

Le petit Robert en donne une liste importante (2ème annexe en fin de volume).

Sinon j'ai trouvé *[cette liste](http://www.lexilogos.com/noms_habitants_villes.htm)*, et *[une carte interactive](http://www.habitants.fr/habitants_departement_loir-et-cher_41.html)* ; et pour le *[Québec](http://www.toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/toponymie-municipale/gentiles/)*.

N.B. *[Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_gentil%C3%A9s)* donne quelques pistes pour la formation des gentilés.

Comment: À noter que Wikipédia donne l'information dans l'article de chaque lieu le nécessitant.

Answer (score 1):

Voici un lien vers la liste des gentilés de Belgique francophone:

http://katsoura.free.fr/site-ortho-gaffe/download/gentiles.pdf

Comment: L'URL se trouvant dans cette [liste](http://www.languefrancaise.cfwb.be/index.php?id=16744) est peut-être meilleur. Merci !