# Y a-t-il des règles pour les noms des habitants des villes ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, toponymes

Le site [lexilogos](https://www.lexilogos.com/noms_habitants_villes.htm) offre une liste exhaustive des noms des habitants des villes françaises tels que :

> Bordelais,  Avignonnais,  Messins,  etc.

Quelles sont les règles qui dictent la formation (ou bien facilitent la mémorisation) de tels noms ?

Comment: Généralement, on ajoute « ais(e) » ou « ien(ne) » mais il y a tellement d'exceptions...

Comment: Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11049/o%C3%B9-trouver-des-sources-fiables-sur-les-gentil%C3%A9s

Comment: @Toto Il y a aussi beaucoup de -ois(e), dans le nord de la France du moins, c'est peut être aussi une question régionale. Il n'y a pas, à ma connaissance de règle générale

Comment: @Flying_whale: Oui, il y a aussi des « ain(e) », « aud(e) » ...

Comment: Petite remarque peut-être inutile: le "nom des habitants de..." s'appelle le gentilé. A ma connaissance il n'y a pas plus de règle en Belgique qu'en France, ce qui explique que parfois les questions de jeu télévisés ou pas sont "Comment appelle-t-on les habitants de ... ?"

Comment: Comme l'a dit @Toto, il y a certaines règles simples mais TELLEMENT d'exceptions. Par exemple, les habitants de Pont-à-Mousson s'appellent les mussipontains (on inverse Pont et Mousson) ou les habitants de St-Étienne s'appellent les Stéphanois (parce que Stéphane et Étienne sont tous deux issus du grec Stephanos qui signifie "le couronné") etc. Tu peux devenir dingue en essayant de trouver des règles là-dedans ! :-)

Comment: @SteffX On retrouve également des exceptions liées à l'histoire de la ville. A Chissey-sur-Loue, Jura, les habitants sont les "babouins", à cause des statues de babouins sur l'église. Les statues étaient là pour protéger l'église, et les habitants ont aussi pris le rôle de "protecteurs". Et puis, à Métabief, Doubs, les habitants sont appelés les Chats-gris (mais je ne sais pas pourquoi cependant).

Comment: @LaurentS.pas plus de règle en Belgique qu'en France, mais une plus grande proportion de -ois (en grande majorité) puis en -ien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il y a des regles, mais il y a plus d'exceptions que de villes qui suivent ces regles.  Reunissez n'importe quel groupe de francais et vous pouvez les jeter dans un jeu de 'qui connait le mieux les vrais noms des habitant' en un clin d'oeil. En fait, les noms des habitants servent a signaler les gens qui Ne Sont Pas Du Coin, ça a une certaine fonction sociale xenophobe..

Answer (score 3):

Les commentaires sont très utiles. Le lien ci-après l'est aussi :

https://polyglotworld.wordpress.com/2017/08/29/memento-des-noms-des-habitants-des-principales-villes-de-france/

D'après ceci :

> Il y a 8 terminaisons principales pour les gentilés français, et une
>   qui est plus rare (pour les noms se terminant en -on) :
>
> -ain  -ais  -ard  -eau  -en  -ien -in -ois  -ot -on
>
> 1.-ain
>
> Montpellier – Montpelliérain
>
> Toulouse ->  Toulousain
>
> 2.-ais
>
> Avignon -> Avignonnais
>
> Bayonne -> Bayonnais
>
> Bordeaux -> Bordelais
>
> Dijon-> Dijonnais
>
> La Rochelle -> Rochelais
>
> Lyon -> Lyonnais
>
> Marseille -> Marseillais
>
> Nantes -> Nantais
>
> Rennes -> Rennais
>
> Toulon -> Toulonnais
>
> 3. -ard
>
> Chamonix -> Chamoniard
>
> 4. -en
>
> Nancy ->Nancéen
>
> Troyes (le nom de la ville se prononce comme le chiffre 3) -> Troyen
>
> 5. -ien
>
> Calais -> Calaisien
>
> Paris-> Parisien
>
> 6. -in
>
> Angers -> Angevin
>
> Besançon -> Bisontin
>
> Poitiers -> Poitevin
>
> Saint Malo -> Malouin
>
> 7. -ois
>
> Aix-en-Provence -> Aixois
>
> Amiens-> Amiénois
>
> Brest -> Brestois
>
> Cannes -> Cannois
>
> Clermont-Ferrand-> Clermontois
>
> Grenoble -> Grenoblois
>
> Lille -> Lillois
>
> Nice -> Niçois
>
> Pau -> Palois
>
> Reims -> Rémois
>
> Saint Etienne -> Stéphanois
>
> Strasbourg -> Strasbourgeois
>
> Valence -> Valentinois
>
> Vichy -> Vichyssois
>
> 8. -ot
>
> Biarritz -> Biarrot (biarrote au féminin)
>
> 9. -on
>
> rare