# Making an adjective from a proper name

Tags: adjectifs, formulation

What are some rules of thumb to construct adjectives from proper names?
E.g.

> Lagrange => Description lagrangienne.
>
> Newton => Mécanique newtonienne.
>
> Euler, Hamilton => eulérien et hamiltonien.

and so on. But,

> Cauchy => ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is probably not popular, I would use *cauchyssois* as an analogy with *Vichy - [vichyssois](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vichyssois)*.

I just found a single occurrence of it:

[Filtres co-cauchyssois](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?14,785303)

There is no specific rule for creating such adjectives. They are built the same way than *gentilés* for which there are no rules either, although there are trends.

See https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentil%C3%A9#La_formation_des_gentil%C3%A9s

Comment: Merci, très bien. Y a-t-il des règles un peu générales ou est-ce un sujet de mémorisation ?

Comment: Oui, je connais les gentilés. J'avais posé une question:-)!

Comment: Voici la question : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31462/y-a-t-il-des-r%C3%A8gles-pour-les-noms-des-habitants-des-villes et une plus vieille :  https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11049/o%C3%B9-trouver-des-sources-fiables-sur-les-gentil%C3%A9s .  Merci encore.

Answer (score 1):

Pour  « Cauchy » on trouve en mathématiques uniquement « de Cauchy », par exemple « une suite de Cauchy ».

> On dit qu'une suite est de Cauchy lorsqu'elle satisfait au critère de Cauchy.